# A harmonic sum with error function

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion, summation-method, summation-by-parts

I need an approximation or a closed form for the series 
$$ \sum_{a=1}^{M}  \frac{1}{a} \, \text{erf} \left(\frac{M}{N} \, a \right)   $$

where $M<N$.

Comment: The relevant comparison is between $M^2$ and $N$, since $\frac{1}{M}\text{erf}\left(\frac{M^2}{N}\right)$ is the last term of the sum. What do we know about that? $M^2\ll N$? $M^2\gg N$?

Comment: If $M^2\gg N$, such sum is approximately $\sum_{a=1}^{M}\frac{1}{a}\approx \log M$.

Comment: No $M^2 \gg N$ is not applicable in our problem. We can say $M^2 \ll N$ is closer to our problem.

Comment: Can you say something more about your problem? What is the origin of such sum? What have you attempted to approximate it or compute it?

Comment: The original problem  
 $$
  \begin{split}   
  P_i^2 & = \sum_{a=1}^{ \sqrt{M} } \sum_{f=0}^{\sqrt{M}-1} \exp \left [-a^2 \left (\frac{ f}{N}  \right )^2   \right] \\
     & =  \sum_{a=1}^{\sqrt{M} } \sum_{f=0}^{\sqrt{M}} \exp \left [-a^2 \frac{M}{N^2} \left (\frac{ f}{\sqrt{M}}  \right )^2   \right] \\
     & =  \sum_{a=1}^{\sqrt{M} } \sum_{f=0}^{\sqrt{M}} \exp \left [- \tilde{a}   \left (\frac{ f}{\sqrt{M}}  \right )^2   \right]
  \end{split}   
 $$

Comment: The inner summation is expressed as Reimann sum (you solved this before in a different question) , hence $$ \begin{split}   
       P_i^2 & =  \sum_{a=1}^{ \sqrt{M} } \frac{\sqrt{M} }{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{\tilde{a}}}\,\text{Erf} \left( \sqrt{\tilde{a}} \right) \\
        & =  \sum_{a=1}^{ \sqrt{M} } \frac{\sqrt{M} }{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi N^2}{a^2  M}}\,\text{Erf} \left( \frac{\sqrt{M}}{N} a \right) \\
       & = \sum_{a=1}^{ \sqrt{M} } \frac{N \sqrt{\pi} }{2 \, a} \, \text{Erf} \left( \frac{\sqrt{M}}{N} a \right).
  \end{split}     $$   $M < N$  but doesn't have to be $M \ll N $

Comment: The outer sum can be reduced to a harmonic sum if $Erf(.)=1$. but that is not our case.

Comment: In such a case just apply Abel's summation. The sum becomes $\log(M)\text{erf}(M^2/N)$ plus a negligible contribute, since the error function quickly converges to $1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59580/discussion-between-assem-and-jack-daurizio).

Comment: It seems a very good direction. Could you please clarify this as an answer, since I am struggling with the integration part in the Ables's summation.